# Url masking / rewriting?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, masking

Hej,

I have url like this: www.something.com. When I hit enter it goes like this path: www.else.com/something/index.html.

Question: How to make something.com display not to change to path?
htaccess?

Domain and server are on same host.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, because you are redirecting to a different domain, you must change the URL. If you were redirecting to somewhere on the same domain (changing the relative path), then you could use an apache `.htaccess` modification for it. (Although the name of that htaccess option escapes me.)

An approach you could take would be using an `iframe` in `www.something.com/index.html`. The iframe could be styled with `min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; position: absolute; margin:0; padding: 0;` and then set the iframe source as `www.else.com/something/index.html`

Comment: thank you for your reply. Iframe is not recommened right ?

Comment: @baribari, it certainly would not be my go-to solution, but I do not think there is another option to redirect it to another domain without actually changing the URL. Although, you could possibly just modify your "VirtualHosts" to set up www.something.com's root directory as the directory for www.else.com. (Effectively 2 complete websites using the same files.) You can find more on that here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html